# fb:google-analytics , does it work for you?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, fbml

I have a Facebook fan page, and some tabs in it. one of which is a static fbml one which besides having and img tag has the following

```
<fb:google-analytics uacct="UA-19191919-4" />
```

problem is.... Facebook ignores this tag and I see no evidence of Google analytics code being executed...

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an iframe for your apps with regular analytic code. Facebook doesn't use FBML anymore.